# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sewar.full_ref'; 'sewar' is not a package

Tags: python, image-processing, mse, sam, ssim

I installed Sewar using `pip install sewar` after that i got same error like below

```
from sewar.full_ref import mse, rmse, psnr, uqi, ssim, ergas, scc, rase, sam, msssim, vifp
import cv2
org = cv2.imread("org_path")
blur = cv2.imread("blur_path")
print("MSE: ", mse(blur, org))
print("RMSE: ", rmse(blur, org))
print("PSNR: ", psnr(blur, org))
print("SSIM: ", ssim(blur, org))
print("UQI: ", uqi(blur, org))
print("MSSSIM: ", msssim(blur, org))
print("ERGAS: ", ergas(blur, org))
print("SCC: ", scc(blur, org))
print("RASE: ", rase(blur, org))
print("SAM: ", sam(blur, org))
print("VIF: ", vifp(blur, org))
```

when i run this code I got this error

```
  from sewar.full_ref import mse, rmse, psnr, uqi, ssim, ergas, scc, rase, sam, msssim, vifp
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sewar.full_ref'; 'sewar' is not a package
```

Comment: Try using conda and trying to install it on a lower version of python and select that as your interpreter, this would most likely fix your problem. Otherwise, you can try pip install [package_name] --upgrade or uninstalling and reinstalling for what its worth.

Comment: Is the `pip` you used for the same version as the python interpreter that gives the error? There are no details in your post that would allow anyone to debug your problem.

Comment: I am curious, what is this package about?